# Email support javascript execution

Tags: javascript, email, gmail

i read over internet email client dont support javascript.

Then how does the `google invite` mail has `Yes | May Be | No`  buttons ?

when i inspect this button they are not links but some java-script get run upon clicking it.

**EDIT:**

In the below image i have show the request generated when i clicked on the `maybe` button.
Now these request is not a link request since the initiator is javascript

[image]

Comment: Javascript onclick then AJAX request Server-Side Language to done i.e.PHP

Comment: When I inspect them, they are links. You are probably looking at at the DOM of your webmail service (which presumably wraps JS around links so it can do tracking or "are you sure?" warnings) and not the email source code itself.

Comment: @kollein — No. NO. Email clients do not execute JavaScript. You can't trigger an Ajax request from an email. (Well, unless you use a link that loads an HTML document in web browser which then does Ajax on load … but doesn't really count).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on a false premise.

Comment: @Quentin i have added a image showing there might be javascript running

Comment: @user2410148 — Yes. JavaScript from the GMail web application not from the email.